# How to get text with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in selenium and web scrapping.

So, I am trying to get text from site specially made for web scrapping, and for some reason i can't do it.I am just get an error "'list' object has no attribute 'text".
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
pages = 10

for page in range(1, pages):
    url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/page/" + str(page) + "/"
    driver.get(url)

    items = len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'quote'))
    total = []
    for item in range(items):
        quotes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'quote').text
        print(quotes)
```

Maybe my imports will help u to understand the reason:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `find_elements` returns a [list of WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements), you need to specify the Element index for which you want to access the `text` property (as there may be more elements with `class=quote`), that's why you are getting the *'list' object has no attribute 'text`* error

You may want to use [`find_element_by_class_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name) method in order to retrieve a single element, or if you want to get the n-th element with `class=quote` you may want to use an index on the List of Elements `elements` returned:

```py
 elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'quote')
 print(elements[2]) #get 3rd element with class=quote
```

If you want further information regarding [Locating Elements using Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), see their documentation.

Comment: Thank u for a reply!
I've just tried your code and I am still getting smth like this: 

`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0c436319c8b2cbf5942b690362da4798", element="25fe6547-188d-4412-b143-450f12937bb3")>`

Comment: I've read documentation on selenium already, but in my case it didn't work. I doesn't really understand why. It just NEED to apply 'text', isn't it?

Comment: I got it! Thank u a lot <3 Just didn't pay enough attention to your answer